# Plugin to "check/uncheck" all matrix blocks while editing entries?

Tags: entries, matrix, control-panel

I did a brief search and didn't pull anything up. Is there a native or easy way to "check/uncheck" all matrix blocks? We have a considerable number of them and this would be extremely helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There's a related feature request for this: ["Expand/collapse all" UI for Matrix fields](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/7425151--expand-collapse-all-ui-for-matrix-fields)

In that feature request, Brandon Kelly explains how this is already supported (it works very well):

> There is a way to achieve this: Check one of the blocks, then hit
>   `Command + A` to select all blocks. Then click the option button on any
>   of the expanded blocks and click "Collapse" to collapse all blocks,
>   and vise-versa to expand all blocks.